# How to Persist React Components with Children after Page Reload Events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, persistence

This is more of a hypothetical question as I would like to have a clear idea before trying to write the code for this problem.

As an example, lets say I have `Board` (parent) and `Card` (children) components.

The `Card`s are placed inside the `Board` and contain some text elements inside (maybe Todo items) and can be moved around inside the board and from board to board. Thus, state is used to allow users to move the cards from board to board, then "check-off" a todo item, and not reset everything to original positions.

But what happens if I want to persist after a user reloads the page?

Is my only option to store everything in `localStorage` after "stringifying", or are there other (better) alternatives?

I see a lot of examples online with a single component where you simply store the state and text of that component, but that seems very inefficient and complex when it comes to components with children.

Comment: I would store the important state in local storage as you suggested. If the state is small you can also add it to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is using localStorage. A full example of how localStorage works, you can change the states with your own.

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'todosvar'

useEffect(() => { 
const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem
(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
if (storedTodos) setTodos(storedTodos)
}, [])

useEffect(() => { 
localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todosvar))
 }, [todosvar])
```

Comment: Yes, but that works for the child component only, what if I want to store all the components (parent and child)?

Comment: Yes you can do this with localStorage, Context API or Redux and create a new state in your Context API or Redux and call it `[store, setStore] = useState({
    todoItem: ""
})`

Then export your Context API objects to child components or any components. Context API is a global component that holds your states and passes it down to children. 

Hope this help!